# Canonical topology on the space of locally bounded finitely additive measures on a ring

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{R}$ be a ring on some set $S$ and $\mu : \mathcal{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a finitely additive real measure. Denote by $|\mu| : \mathcal{R} \to [0, \infty]$ its variation measure.

- $\mu$ is bounded if $\sup_{A \in \mathcal{R}} |\mu(A)| < \infty$
- $\mu$ is locally bounded (or equivalently has finite variation)
  if $\sup_{B \subseteq A, B \in \mathcal{R}} |\mu(B)| < \infty$ for all $A \in \mathcal{R}$ (or equivalently $|\mu|(A) < \infty$ for all $A \in \mathcal{R}$)

The set $ba(\mathcal{R})$ of all bounded finitely additive real measures $\mu : \mathcal{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a vector space and $\lVert \mu \rVert := \sup_{A \in \mathcal{R}} |\mu(A)|$ a norm on $ba(\mathcal{R})$ which turns this space into a Banach space. If $\mathcal{R}$ is an algebra then $\lVert \mu \rVert = |\mu|(S)$.

Just for interest, we can also consider the vector space of locally bounded finitely additive measures on $\mathcal{R}$. Let us denote it by $lba(\mathcal{R})$. What is a canonical (locally convex) topology on this space? 
(Note also that if $\mathcal{R}$ is a $\delta$-ring then every real measure on $\mathcal{R}$ is locally bounded [Dinculeanu, "Vector measures", Section I.§3].)

Comment: The seminorms $p_A(\mu)=\sup\{|\mu(B)|: B\subseteq A,\, B\in\mathcal R\}$ look canonical.

Comment: Indeed, thank you.